# How Do I Check When the Spacebar is Pressed

Tags: javascript

Right now I am using

```
function press(){
if (32 in keysDown) {

}
}
```

and

```
setInterval(press, 1)
```

It detects when the spacebar is down.  I want to know the easiest way to detect when its pressed.  I have tried looking for a solution myself but everywhere I've gone its been for jQuery.

Comment: can you share a fiddle ?

Comment: Before proceeding with keyCode/charCode/which/whatever, please consider the [*MDN KeyboardEvent*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) article.

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your javascript function.

```
var IsSpaceBarPressed = false;
if (evt.keyCode == 32) {
  IsSpaceBarPressed = false;
}
else {
  IsSpaceBarPressed = true;
}
```

Comment: why is the else in the if?

Comment: Indeed: `var IsSpacePressed = event.keyCode == 32;`, though [*keyCode*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) is deprecated so support for *key* should be tested first.

Answer (score 1):

you can bind the keypress event to a function

```
document.getElementById("hello").onkeypress = function (evt) {
    var k = evt ? evt.which : window.event.keyCode;
    if (k == 32) {
        return false;
    }
}​
```